# Is it possible to change the viewport size on a PC?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the site open on a screen above 1366px as if the viewport is 1366px. That is, to make the site look the same on fullHD, 2k, 4k, and take up about 80% of the screen width.
[I want.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY4J0.jpg)

At the moment I know two solutions that do not fit.

1. use the transform scale or zoom css styles.
   This method is not suitable because there are problems with parallax and other js effects. Also Transform uses the GPU, which can be disabled.
2. use the vw unit.
   I can't rule this option out, but I can't call it convenient. However, there will still be problems with js, and I wouldn't want to rewrite js for vw.

In any case, both of these solutions do not work for me. With them I only enlarge the site, not reduce the size of the viewport.

In browsers, you can zoom in with the Ctrl + "+-" combination. In this case, the viewport will change. In this case, everything works as it should and there are no problems with JS. The value of window.devicePixelRatio will also change.
[zoom browser.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBxEK.jpg)

Question:
Is there any way to change the size of the viewport?

Is there any way to set your window.devicePixelRatio to make the viewport scale change. I tried making window.devicePixelRatio = 2, but nothing changes.

Comment: The viewport is the size of the window. It comes from whatever size the user makes it. `window.devicePixelRatio` is also set by the browser based on the device. It can be faked using the dev tools. The CSS viewport units are specifically designed to size things _based on the viewport_

Comment: If you want a static pixel size, hard code the *main* wrapper for your site in your CSS...

Comment: @dalelandry I don't think that's what the OP is asking. AFAIK they'd like a site that is always 80% of the viewport. Not a static pixel size?

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY4J0.jpg

Comment: @dale-landry https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY4J0.jpg

Comment: @nastya97core that picture doesn’t really explain much. You cannot control the size of the viewport, but you can control the sizing of the html inside it